# Running chrome using docker-selenium, authentication socks5 proxy on python

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, socks5

## Main problem

I need to run chrome using docker. I have found [docker images on github](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium), using this I have tried to run chrome.

```py
options = ChromeOptions()
os.system(f'docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size="2g" -e SCREEN_WIDTH={width} -e SCREEN_HEIGHT={height} --platform linux/amd64 selenium/standalone-chrome:latest')
while True:
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', options=options)
    except (ProtocolError, RemoteDisconnected):
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
    break
```

But it raise (docker exactly running, because past code on firefox worked)

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I've tried to set location to chrome but I don't seem to be able to find the correct location.

Also I've found [similar error on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t), but "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage" options not works for me.

## Previous problems

My target is to run selenium on docker to hide browser automation by resizing the screen. Also because of this I need to use a proxy. I have a socks5 proxy with authentication.

I have used firefox on docker, but it not works with socks5 authentication proxy. Although `seleniumwire` was able to connect proxy to firefox, it didn't work on docker. Docker environment variables and firefox settings failed to connect it too.

Before that I tried to replace the values returned by `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height` with JS, but I couldn't find a way to do it without docker.

So, if you know how to connect auth socks5 proxy to Firefox or simulate different screen resolution, this will help me.

#### Configuration

MacOS Ventura 13.2.1 on M1
Chrome 113.0.5672.63
Python 3.10